# Best email server for CentOS?

Tags: email, centos

I want to install email server on my CentOS server but just don't know which email server is the best. Any suggestion? I have option to use Google Apps or Outlook email servers but I should install my own email server on my CentOS better.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is small private use, use the good old stable `postfix`, which is part of CentOS.